# how to reduce the calculation time of optimizer.step() without loss.item() in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

When I　test my imagenet model's calculation time, I found that if　tensor like loss or top1, top5 don't be transformed by function `tensor.item()` or `tensor.cpu().data.numpy()`, the calculation time of `optimizer.step()` will be greatly increased as shown below.

```
total_top1 = torch.tensor(0.).cuda()  # The first case
total_top5 = torch.tensor(0.).cuda()  # The first case
total_loss = torch.tensor(0.).cuda()  # The first case
# total_top1 = 0.0 # The second case
# total_top5 = 0.0 # The second case 
# total_loss = 0.0 # The second case

outputs, loss = model(images, path, labels, criterion, gpu_nums)

st = time.time()
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad()
total_to += time.time() - st # step() time

top1, top5 = accuracy(outputs, labels, topk=(1, 5))

st = time.time()
total_counter += images.size(0)
# total_top1 += top1.cpu().data.numpy() #  or top1.item() # The second case
# total_top5 += top5.cpu().data.numpy() # The second case
# total_loss += loss.cpu().data.numpy() # The second case
total_top1 += top1 # The first case
total_top5 += top5 # The first case
total_loss += loss # The first case
total_ti += time.time() - st # data transform time
```

In first case, `total_to` = 18.0s, `total_ti` = 0.2s for 100 iterations calculation.But in second case, `total_to` = 8s, `total_ti` = 9s.

I tried to find the reason for this kind of difference.The most plausible answer is that `item()` prevents the newly calculated variable from entering the calculation graph, so the `step()`'s time is reduced.However, when I run the code below:

```
outputs, loss = model(images, path, labels, criterion, gpu_nums)

st = time.time()
optimizer.step()
optimizer.zero_grad()
total_to += time.time() - st # step() time

st = time.time()
total_counter += images.size(0)
# loss.item() 
total_ti += time.time() - st # data transform time
```

`total_to` is still around 18s, and `total_ti` = 0s.When using loss.item(), `total_to` change to 8s, but `total_ti` changes to 9s.

So could you tell me what's the reason there in pytorch and how could I make `total_ti` be 0s and `total_to` be 8s? Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: In the second code block can you try putting a `torch.cuda.synchronize()` before `total_to += ...`? I think this is occurring because the GPU code executes everything asynchronously until you request a value then it needs to synchronize anyway to finish evaluation.

Comment: Thank you！I have tried it as you said, and the results confirm that this kind of  phenomenon is caused by the asynchronous of pytorch.